# Dynamically update TreeViewer from eclipse plugin

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, jface

I am creating a eclipse plugin which requires TreeViewer to be dynamically updated when domain object changes.

I have found one article from eclipse site

http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/TreeViewerArticle.htm?PHPSESSID=4d48764999a9cb66a7fd58a954ef2131

This article mentions below code to register for domain object changes

```
/** Because the domain model does not have a richer
 * listener model, recursively add this listener
 * to each child box of the given box. */
protected void addListenerTo(MovingBox box) {
    box.addListener(this);
    for (Iterator iterator = box.getBoxes().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
       MovingBox aBox = (MovingBox) iterator.next();
       addListenerTo(aBox);
    }
}
```

It mentions addListener method of `MovingBox` which is supposedly the domain object in this case. The article does not provide any code samples for `MovingBox` implementation. I am facing lot of difficulty in understanding where `addListener` method came from?

I have searched a lot on web to find any working example of Treeview which can get dynamically updated on domain changes. Not sure if I am searching for right thing. Can someone please help me regarding the same?

Comment: All the source code for this example is included in the [download link](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/cbg.article.treeviewer.zip) given in the 'Source Code' section at the beginning of the article

Comment: oh didn't noticed that in bit hurry, Please post it as a answer.  Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the source code for this TreeViewer example is available in the link given in the 'Source Code' section at the start of the article.

The link is http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-TreeViewer/cbg.article.treeviewer.zip